# Find the number of Ordered pairs $(A,B,C)$ where, $ A \subseteq B $ and $ B \subset C $ and $ C \subseteq X$. Where $X =$ {$1,2,...,n$}

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

**My Attempt :**

I considered that $ C \subseteq X$. Thus, $|C|= 2^n - 1$. And $C \neq $ {$\phi$} because $ B \subset C $ condition will be violated.

I haven't considered {$\phi$} in $B$ or $A$. Should we consider it ? If yes, then why ?

Then I found the number of elements in $B$ for each $C$, which would be having different elements of $A$ corresponiding to each subset $B$. Thus we would have :

$$ \sum_{k=1} ^ {n-1} { {n-1} \choose k} \sum_{r =1} ^ k {k \choose r} = 2.3^{n-1} - (n+3)2^{n-2} -4 $$

pairs of $A$ and $B$ where $\displaystyle \sum_{r =1} ^ k {k \choose r}$ repesents the number of elements in $A$ corresponding to each subset $B$.

Then the total number of pairs of $(A,B,C)$ will be

> $\displaystyle (2^n - 1) \times \sum_{k=1} ^ {n-1} { {n-1} \choose k} \sum_{r =1} ^ k {k \choose r} = 2(2^n - 1)(3^{n-1} - (n+3)2^{n-3} -2)$

Please verify it, I am not sure if it is correct.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My initial thought is that we would have four possibilities for each $x \in X$, namely $x \in X - C$, $x \in C - B$, $x \in B - A$, $x \in A$.  What I have to think about is how to handle the requirement that $B$ is a proper subset of $C$.

Comment: That seems interesting.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig My idea exactly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can count all functions $f: \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \to \{0,1,2,3\}$ that assume the value $3$ at least once. Such a function "encodes" such a triple by setting $A=f^{-1}[\{1\}]$, $B=f^{-1}[\{1,2\}]$, $C=f^{-1}[\{1,2,3\}]$. The inclusions are obvious and if $3$ is assumed as a value $f(i)$, $B \subsetneq C$ as witnessed by $i$. And conversely, for every triple $(A,B,C)$ we can define a function $f$ by 
$$f(i)=\begin{cases}0 & x \notin C\\
                    1 & x \in A\\
                    2 & x \in B, x \notin A\\
                    3 & x \in C, x \notin B
       \end{cases}$$
So the set of such functions and such triples has the same size.

There are $4^n$ many functions ($n$ choices from $4$ values). And $3^n$ of them do not assume $3$ (because we have one "forbidden value").

This makes the answer $4^n - 3^n$.

Comment: An elegant approach.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you. I hope it enlightens the OP.

Comment: We can verify Henno's answer for small $n$.  If $n = 1$, we must have $A = B = \emptyset, C = \{1\}$.  Notice that $4^1 - 3^1 = 1$.  If $n = 2$, there are seven possibilities: \begin{align*} & A = B = \emptyset, C = \{1\}\\ & A = B = \emptyset, C = \{2\}\\ & A = B = \emptyset, C = \{1, 2\}\\ & A = \emptyset, B = \{1\}, C = \{1, 2\}\\ & A = \emptyset, B = \{2\}, C = \{1, 2\}\\ & A = \{1\}, B = \{1\}, C = \{1, 2\}\\ & A = \{2\}, B = \{2\}, C = \{1, 2\} \end{align*}  Notice that $4^2 - 3^2 = 7$.

Comment: So we must consider $\phi $ in Subsets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer completely. Please simplify it a bit, it's too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi what exactly isn't clear? Do you understand the correspondence between the functions and the triples of subsets?

Comment: Yes, that is the doubt. I am not regular to such questions.

Comment: And what does inverse $f^{-1}$ mean here... ?

Comment: $A$ is the set of points with value $1$, $B$ the set with value $1$ or $2$, $C$ the set with value $1$ or $2$ or $3$. In general $f^{-1}[A]=\{x: f(x) \in A\}$. @NikolaAlfredi

Comment: Ok... How is there a correspondense between the set and the function.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi If you have three sets $A,B,C$ as the problem asks to count (so $A \subseteq B \subsetneq C$ we define $f$ as I described (we distinguish 4 types of points, really, those in $A$, those not in $C$, and the ones in the "layers" between $A$ and $B$ and $B$ and $C$. One layer is non-empty, so that type *must* occur.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi For every function in $F=\{f: \{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}\to\{0,1,2,3\}: \exists i: f(i)=3\}$ there is exactly one such triple in $T=\{(A,B,C): A \subseteq B \subsetneq C \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and for every triple in $T$ there is exactly one $f \in F$. So there is a bijection between the set $T$ you want to count with the set of functions $F$, which is easier to count. This is a common idea in combinatorics.

Comment: Actually, the case is that, yesterday I learn't what are Bijective functions and One to one correspondence, so I haven't mastered them yet. I am trying to understand your answer using your replies. Thank you.

Comment: What do " one layer is not empty mean " ? and which layer is that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105192/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-nikola-alfredi).