# $A= \{1,2,...,n\} $. Find number of pairs $ \langle B,C \rangle $ for which $ B,C \subseteq A ~$ , $~ |B| = k $ and $ B \cap C = \emptyset $

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem**: Denote $ A = \{ 1,2,...,n \} $ where $ n \geq 1 $ is natural and suppose $ k $ is natural s.t. $ 1 \leq k \leq n $. Find the number of pairs $ \langle B,C \rangle $ for which $ B,C \subseteq A ~~$ , $~~ |B| = k $ and $  B \cap C  = \emptyset $

**Final answer from book:**  $ { n \choose k } \cdot 2^{n-k} $

> **There is a hint in the question which directs to the following problem ( it may help ):**
> Hint: *What is the number of strings of length $ n $ in which only the digits $ 0,1,2 $ appear and $ 1 $ appears exactly $ k  $ times?*
> **My Answer ( it is correct ):** Chose $ k  $ indexes where to put $ 1 $, this'll be $ { n \choose k } $. Next, we're left to place $ 0 ,2 $ in the $ n-k $ indexes leftover, so the number of choices for this will be $ 2^{n-k} $. In total, the number of choices is $ { n \choose k } \cdot 2^{n-k} $ .

**My attempt:**
for every $ i \in \{ 1,2,...,n \} $
there are 2 options for $ B $:  $~ i \in B  $ or $ i \notin B  $
there are 2 options for $ C $:  $~ i \in C  $ or $ i \notin C  $
there are $ 2 \cdot 2 = 4 $ options in total.
We also have that $ B \cap C = \emptyset $; this means $ i \notin B $ and $ i \notin C $, so we have 3 options in total. In total the number of pairs $ \langle B,C \rangle $  is  $ 3^n $.

My attempt is wrong, I didn't know really what to do ( there's this answer [Find the number of Ordered pairs $(A,B,C)$ where, $ A \subseteq B $ and $ B \subset C $ and $ C \subseteq X$. Where $X =$ {$1,2,...,n$}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570135/find-the-number-of-ordered-pairs-a-b-c-where-a-subseteq-b-and-b-sub)  , but I didn't fully understand how it relates to the hint above  ), can you please help me? I feel like I don't know how to approach this combinatorical problem...

**Edit**:
Here's the answer from the book:
for every  pair $ \langle B,C \rangle $ in which $ B,C \subseteq A $ , $ |B| = k $ we'll correspond a single string of length $ n $ via the following rule:
for every $ i \in \{  1,2,...,n\} $ we write in the $i-th $ spot in the string the following:
$ 1 $ if $ i \in B $
$ 2 $ if $ i \in C $
$ 0  $ if $ i \notin B  $ and $ i \notin C $ .
From this , the number of pairs $ \langle B,C \rangle $ in which $ B,C \subseteq A $ , $ |B| = k $  is equal to the number of strings given in the hint above, that is , $ { n \choose k } \cdot 2^{n-k} $.

Comment: Your attempt is wrong because nowhere did you take into account the condition that $|B|=k$.  You answered the question of finding pairs $(B,C)$ such that $B,C\subseteq A$ and $B\cap C=\emptyset$ with no other restrictions, in particular without the restriction that $|B|=k$

Comment: Isn't the problem clear?  There are $\binom nk$ ways to choose the set $B$ and for each choice of $B$ there are $2^{n-k}$ subsets of $A-B$ you can choose for $C$.  The hint seems to be the long way round the barn...or have I misread something?

Comment: @lulu Maybe you're right, but it was too simple to notice, In my book the solution is different than that, i'll edit my answer and  provide it.

Comment: The hint is just a restatement of the original problem (where the $1's$ mark the elements of $B$ and for $C$ we can take either the $0's$ or the $2's$).  So the hint instantly solves the problem, though I don't really see the value in the restatement (if it provides intuition then of course it is good, though does it?)

Comment: As an aside, if we were to relax the condition that $B$ must be of size $k$ and allow $B$ to be any size, your work shows the total should be $3^n$ while another approach would be to break apart into cases according to the size of $B$, using the correct answer to the original problem for each of these individual cases this yields the identity then of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}=3^n$, a special case of the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) looking at the expansion of $(1+2)^n$

Comment: @lulu the answer you provided is much clearer than that which is provided in the book ( I edited the post and provided it ), I understand it now, thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way too simple actually. 
First you want to choose $k$ elements out of $n$ elements to $B$, so there are $n \choose k$ ways of doing this. For each way, as your conditions imply $C$ is a subset of $A-B$ which contains $n-k$ elements, so there are $2^{n-k}$ choices. In total, there are ${n \choose k}2^{n-k}$ possibilities.